# How to get window.location.href by using an EventListener assigned to a JS variable containing html

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the window.location.href with a username added to the end of it using .concat() to appear in the console. The EventListner only works for the first fullname(fln) and it displays both users window.location.href with their username. How do I get it to display window.location.href with a username for that specific user in the console and for it to work on multiple users full names (fln)?

```
usersRef.get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      var downloadURL = doc.data().downloadURL;
      var fln = doc.data().fln;
      let i = 0;
      display(i, downloadURL);
      var username = doc.data().username;
      const queryString = window.location.href;

      function display(row) {
        let new_html = '';
        new_html += '<tr>';
        new_html += '<td>';
        new_html += '<td>';
        new_html += '<div class="grid-item">';
        new_html += '<img src= "' + downloadURL + '">';
        new_html += '<h2 class="fln"> ' + fln + '';
        new_html += '</h2>';
        new_html += '</div>';
        new_html += '</td>';
        new_html += '</td>';
        new_html += '</tr>';
        new_html += row;
        $('#grid-container').append(new_html);
        let eachName = document.querySelector(".fln"); 
        eachName.addEventListener("click", userClicked);
        function userClicked() {
          var i = 0;
          const queryString = window.location.href;
          console.log(queryString.concat('/', username));
       }
    
      
     
    
     }

    })  
 })
```

Comment: Use `+` instead of `concat` for performance. Also, you're calling `display` with 2 args when it only takes one.

Answer (score 1):

```
let eachName = document.querySelector(".fln");
```

will select the *first* element on the page with that class, not the one you just added to the table. So every time through the loop you're adding another click listener to the element in the first row of the table, while the rest will not have any listener.

Use

```
let eachName = document.querySelector("#grid-container tr:last-child .fln");
```

to select the the one in the last row, which will be the one that was just added.

Comment: I pasted  let eachName = document.querySelector("#grid-container tr:last-child .fnl"); in place of  let eachName = document.querySelector(".fln"); but I am getting this error  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: I had a typo: `.fnl` should be `.fln`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo but now I'm getting this error  explore.js:71 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#grid-container tr:last-child. fln' is not a valid selector.

Comment: `tr:last-child. fln` should be `tr:last-child .fln`

Comment: Can't you check for typos yourself?

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
function userClicked() {
                    var i = 0;
                    const queryString = window.location.href;
                    console.log(queryString.concat('/', username));
                    window.location = queryString.concat('/', username);
                }
```

Comment: Please add a description to your answer.